# Fill data to array and continue iteration in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array with this data

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'];
```

I need to wrap this information into groups of **12 positions**.
In this case, it would be:

```
$row[0] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'];
$row[1] = ['m'];
```

How could I do this dynamically, where the array length could change but should always be grouped by 12?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried `array_chunk`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: @DanCostinel I didn't know this function. Amazing, thanks!

Comment: did you tried `anything`?